# How do I export html/css to A4 pdf using PhantomJS without causing overflow on each page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf-generation, phantomjs

I'm creating a web based text editor and I want a server based solution (preferably using PhantomJS) to export the documents as pdf in A4 size with no margins. Unfortunately I can't get my pages to export correctly. I managed to get a close to perfect pdf using print to pdf in chrome, but exporting the same page using the latest version of PhantomJS results in ~1mm overflow on each page which creates a lot of almost empty pages.

This is my test html, three A4 sized pages with different background colors:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Print test</title>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        html,
        body {
            width: 210mm;
        }
        .page {
            page-break-after: always;
            width: 210mm;
            height: 297mm;
        }
        @page {
            size: A4;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page" style="background-color:red;"></div>
    <div class="page" style="background-color:green;"></div>
    <div class="page" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is how I print it using 'phantom' package for node (mac os x):

```js
phantom = require('phantom')

phantom.create(function(ph) {
    ph.createPage(function(page) {
        page.set('paperSize', {
            width: '210mm',
            height: '297mm'
        });
        page.open("http://127.0.0.1:56587/print_test.html", function(status) {
            page.render('out.pdf', function() {
                console.log('Page Rendered');
                ph.exit();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

It is possible to export pages like these in A4 size without margins and not cause overflow?